# Excel VBA. If Some Cell has a 0, Enter "TBD" in another Cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to auto populate a cell with one of three strings, PASS, FAIL and TBD

The code I have below works for the PASS and FAIL senerios, but not for TBD

In one column (column A) I have the name of a bunch of files. If the filename contains the string "ANT" I have a tripping value, to populate a FAIL, of any value less than 9.54

Else, set the tripping value to 25.

What I would actually like is the following:

If the value contains *SPT*-*-SPT* (where the astrics are any values before or after SPT) I have the tripping value set to 25

Else, if I see a 0 in column H enter "TBD" in column L

The latest code used a formula and is as follows:

```
Sub PassFail()

  'Specify which sheet (name) of the active workbook we want to work on
  With Sheets("(5) Coax Cable Sweeps Table")

    'Determine the range we want to put values into
    With .Range("L1:L" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

      'Put the standard worksheet formula into all cells at once by specifying the formula for the 1st cell only
      'Note that any quote marks in the actual formula need to be doubled up at this point

      'This line does not consider any zeros for DTF measurments taken without a load
      .Formula = "=IF(H1<IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""ANT"",A1)),9.54,25),""Fail"",""Pass"")"


      'The below formula DOES NOT WORK as intended.
      '.Formula = "=IF(H1=0,""TBD"",""=IF(H1<IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""""ANT"""",A1)),9.54,25),""""Fail"""",""""Pass"""")"")"

      .Value = .Value
     End With
    End With


End Sub
```

I then tried to use If, elseIf logic and came up with the following:

```
Sub PassFail_v1()




    Dim x   As Long


    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(8)
        For x = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If InStr(.Cells(x, 1).Value, "ANT") > 0 Then
                .Cells(x, 12).Value = IIf(.Cells(x, 8).Value < 9.54, "Fail", "Pass")

            ElseIf InStr(.Cells(x, 1).Value, "*SPT*-*STP*") > 0 Then
                .Cells(x, 12).Value = IIf(.Cells(x, 8).Value < 25, "Fail", "Pass")

           ' Else
            '    .Cells(x, 12).Value = IIf(.Cells(x, 8).Value = 0, "TBD", " ")

            End If
        Next x
    End With




    Application.ScreenUpdating = True




End Sub
```

Which still doesn't work.. 
Some cells in column L are left blank, others with a 0 in column H show TBD in column L (which is nice), and others show FAILS at a 0 when they shouldn't.

Any advice?

Comment: Sample data would be helpful.

Comment: Maybe a UDF would be a better design than a macro...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if I understand your code and your desired result, you are looking at Column A and if any part of the string in A(n) contains "ANT", the value to determine Pass/Fail is 9.54. If any part of A(n) contains the string "*SPT*-*STP*", then the pass/fail value is 25 (btw, using wildcards in a search requires `LIKE` and evaluates to a boolean.) However, if Column H contains a 0, then L(n) should be "TBD" regardless of the value in A(n), correct? If that's the case, you need two IF statements, with the one evaluating column H after the one evaluating Column A:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(8)
    For x = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If InStr(.Cells(x, 1).Value, "ANT") > 0 Then
            .Cells(x, 12).Value = IIf(.Cells(x, 8).Value < 9.54, "Fail", "Pass")
        ElseIf .Cells(x, 1).Value Like "*SPT*-*STP*" Then
            .Cells(x, 12).Value = IIf(.Cells(x, 8).Value < 25, "Fail", "Pass")
        End If

        If .Cells(x, 8).Value = 0 Then 
        '    .Cells(x, 12).Value = "TBD"
        End If
    Next x
End With
```

Addendum: It should be noted that if A(n) does not contain either "ANT" or some form of "*SPT*-*STP*", L(n) will be left blank. So if you see cells in column L that are blank, look at column A and determine what you want to do in those cases.

Comment: Thank you, your statement was exactly correct. I will use LIKE for wildcards, I never knew it was needed for searching strings. The code looks great and makes logical sense. It works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

You have enclosed the second part of the formula in quotes. As it's additional to the formula, the `=` sign and the extra quotes are not needed

```
.Formula = "=IF(H1=0,""TBD"",""=IF(H1<IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""""ANT"""",A1)),9.54,25),""""Fail"""",""""Pass"""")"")"
```

should be

```
.Formula = "=IF(H1=0,""TBD"",IF(H1<IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""ANT"",A1)),9.54,25),""Fail"",""Pass""))"
```

Comment: This change you implemented/suggested makes the original code run perfectly. This is also a suggested approach as it uses formulas and speads up the processing of large amounts of data since it populates one function to all cells in the range which is quicker than doing it one cell at a time. Thanks!